# Why can I not access a selector of dynamic content in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I'm adding dynamic content to my pages to limit the amount of form controls to only what the user needs.  I use the following code to get information from a drop-down-list for what choice the user made, and then I change another control that restricts the information they can search on.  So for instance, instead of allowing someone to perform a search like `first_name = 47`, I change the form control to a text box that will only accept certain characters -- limiting them to something like `first_name = Steve`.

```
  $('body').on 'change', 'select[name$="[name]"]', ->

    # This block is simply figuring out which element was changed and locating it's corresponding form control where the user inputs information.
    name_string = $(this).attr 'id'
    selected_value = $("option:selected", this).text().toLowerCase()
    value_id = $(this).attr('id').replace('name', 'value')
    value_id = value_id.replace('a','v')

    # This block is executed if the attribute the user wishes to search on should only be true/false
    if attributes_for_true_false_select.indexOf(selected_value) > -1

      # Create a true/false drop down list with the correct `name` and `id` attributes
      true_false_drop_down_list = '<select class="form-control" name="' + $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('name') +
        '" id="' + $('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('id') + '"><option value="1">True</option><option value="0">False</option></select>'

      # Replace the current form selector with the new true/false drop down list
      $('#'+value_id).replaceWith(true_false_drop_down_list)

    else if ...
```

Now the above code works fine, but only for the first time.  After I've changed the form control once, then try and do it again, the code returns 'undefined' for `$('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('name')` and `$('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('id')`.  I think it's because the content didn't exist prior and so the code can't find it after it was dynamically added.  Though I expected adding the listener to $('body') would have solved this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Is your new element matching `select[name$="[name]"]` selector???

Comment: Thought I had it figured out and was missing the `[value]` being at the end of my value control string -- but that turned out to not be the case.  Yes the [name] selector still matches for what I can tell. That element is never changed only the corresponding [value] form.

Comment: Why don't you use string interpolation (`$("input[id='#{value_id}']")`) instead of all the escaping and `+`ing? Reads a bit better.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks wasn't aware

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the section where I build up the new form control I'm inserting.. `$('input[id=\''+value_id+'\']').attr('id')` -- I just needed to remove the `input` part of that and simply find by the id attribute.  This is because some of the form controls I'm adding aren't `input`, such as the shown `select`.